# Postgres WAL Lag with Debezium CDC Source Connector, requires connector restart to fix

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

First of all thanks for all the hard work and support you guys provide. I'm reaching out as I've exhausted all my efforts to determine an issue I am encountering with Debezium Postgres CDC Source Connector (1.4.1) that is being host in Confluent Kafka Connect (6.0.x). The issue we are seeing is random times throughout the day the Connector will seemingly stall and the the Postgres WAL Lag will start to climb, the connector for the most part does not recover, a restart of the connector task is required.

We ran Java Flight Recorder on the Kafka Connect instance during a problem period and came out with this stack trace:

```
at java.sql.SQLException.setNextException(java.sql.SQLException)
at void java.sql.SQLWarning.setNextWarning(java.sql.SQLWarning) 
at void org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutorBase.addWarning(java.sql.SQLWarning) 
at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyOperationImpl org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyOperationImpl, boolean) 
at void org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyOperationImpl, boolean) 
at byte[] org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(boolean) 
at java.nio.ByteBuffer org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(boolean) 
at java.nio.ByteBuffer org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(boolean) 
at java.nio.ByteBuffer org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending() 
at boolean io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.readPending(io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.ReplicationStream$ReplicationMessageProcessor) 
at void io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.processMessages(io.debezium.pipeline.source.spi.ChangeEventSource$ChangeEventSourceContext, io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.ReplicationStream) 
at void io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(io.debezium.pipeline.source.spi.ChangeEventSource$ChangeEventSourceContext) 
at void io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(io.debezium.pipeline.spi.OffsetContext, io.debezium.pipeline.source.spi.ChangeEventSource$ChangeEventSourceContext) 
at void io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0() 
at void io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator$$Lambda$860.1129257263.run() 
at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() 
at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) 
at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() at void java.lang.Thread.run()
```

Looking through Github I can find the `addWarning` method call as described by the trace. It looks like it occurs due to an `N` char in the response. I've tried doing some googling to better understand what is occuring or what this means but am coming up empty handed.

Line in source where addWarning is called (I think) - https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/45a771fccd77c1211d8638111ee3e9934849b781/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L1217

The problem has existed for some time and we've just been dealing with it.

A few things we've tried:

- Adjusting Connector Configuration, Batch Sizes, Linger, etc...
- Adjusting Heap
- Adjusted Garbage Collection Parameters
- Upgrading to Debezium 1.4.1
- Allocating more CPU to pod in Kubernetes

No logs are output to stdout during this unrecoverable error, I don't have any additional information other than the stack trace above as I am not able to remotely debug. Would be curious to know if anyone else has encountered this issue or is intimately familiar with the Debezium Source.

Comment: Can you try to look few rows before the stacktrace output is there more useful information? Please share , thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I get, bottom -> up. The exceptions, warnings from the final methods are never logged anywhere. I'm just at a loss as to what the actual cause is, any advice on PgSQL logging would be helpful.

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?loggerLevel=TRACE&loggerFile=pgjdbc.log

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?loggerLevel=DEBUG

Comment: Hey.  Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm seeing a similar problem with the Debezium Postgres CDC Source connector.  I'm using Confluent Cloud though and have less visibility into what's going on.

Comment: @Bikerdan we did resolve the lag on WAL with Debezium by providing additional configuration via the `slot.stream.params`configuration property on the connector. While our connector was configured to include only a subset of tables from the database that meant the filtering was done connector side. By filtering on the server-side we never encountered this issue again. Link - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-slot-stream-params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**

We resolved this by providing a filtering rule to `slot.stream.params` property within our connector configuration. By doing so we tuned the replication slot to filter out unnecessary tables and only send over the tables we required, this filtering is done server-side before sending them to our connector.

For more information about this configuration property you can see it here: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-slot-stream-params

**Example Config:**

```
{
  "name": "fulfillment-connector",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", 
    "database.hostname": "192.168.99.100", 
    "database.port": "5432", 
    "database.user": "postgres", 
    "database.password": "postgres", 
    "database.dbname" : "postgres", 
    "topic.prefix": "fulfillment", 
    "table.include.list": "public.inventory",
    "slot.stream.params": "add-tables=public.inventory" // This enabled the filtering server-side
  }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized pgoutput option: add-tables

Comment: According to code, there is no such option in pgoutput https://doxygen.postgresql.org/pgoutput_8c.html
But there is   "slot.stream.params": "publication_names=dbz_publication",